# Why json doesn´t work?

Tags: java, json, libgdx

When I try to run my project my game crash with this error:

```
Exception in thread "LWJGL Application" java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.badlogic.gdx.utils.Json.writeValue(Json.java:376)
at com.mygdx.game.MyGdxGame.write(MyGdxGame.java:30)
at com.mygdx.game.MyGdxGame.create(MyGdxGame.java:25)
at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication.mainLoop(LwjglApplication.java:136)
at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication$1.run(LwjglApplication.java:114)
```

And the code is:

```
private Json json;
private int x = 1;

@Override
public void create() {

    json = new Json();
    write(json);
}

@Override
public void write(Json json) {
    json.writeValue("X", x);

}
```

What is the problem? I can't find the solution

Comment: You can't resolve this without debug or trace.

Comment: You need to learn how to debug.  It's a skill that all programmers must have, to accomplish anything at all.  And debugging a NullPointerException is one of the easiest debug tasks and a good place to start learning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the [source code](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/gdx/src/com/badlogic/gdx/utils/Json.java), it looks like the problem is that you haven't set a writer. It's not clear what you *expect* `writeValue` to do when you haven't set a writer, but you either need to change which method you call (e.g. calling `prettyPrint` instead), or set the writer first.

For example:

```
private Json json;
private StringWriter writer;

writer = new StringWriter();
json = new Json();
json.setWriter(writer);
write(json);
```

Then you can use `writer.toString()` to get the JSON out later.

Comment: Thank you, but how can i save this information into a json file?

Comment: @ElPunto: Use an OutputStreamWriter instead, wrapping a FileOutputStream?

Comment: Can you write a example?

Comment: @Elpuntorojo: Not on this question, no - it's got nothing to do with what you asked. Stack Overflow works well for very specific questions - not questions which evolve because the author basically wants hand-holding through a series of steps. I suggest you read https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Reading-&-writing-JSON and if you're still confused, write a *new* question with details of what you've tried and what went wrong, etc - as well as the context of what you're trying to achieve. (You haven't told us that *at all* at the moment.)